# How to get absolute URL in production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to get the absolute URL in the production build when using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const url =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : "https://websitename.vercel.app";
  const res = await fetch(`${url}/api/posts`);
  const posts = await res.json();
  console.log("posts: ", posts);

  const paths = posts.map(({ slug }) => ({
    params: { slug },
  }));

  console.log("Paths: ", paths);

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  console.log("params: ", params);
  const url =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : "https://websitename.vercel.app";
  const res = await fetch(`${url}/api/post`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: params.slug,
  });
  const post = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { post },
  };
}
```

It works fine in the development build but when it comes to production it fails because the hardcoded `https://websitename.vercel.app` is not the one generated by `vercel`. The URL generated by `vercel` is something like this `websitename-q1hdjf6c2.vercel.app`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use `${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/my/route`.

Check

[Vercel environment variables](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables#system-environment-variables)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, since static site building process is done without an actual site running, the full URL is not accessible there. You can only access the full URL on the client side in the global `window` object.

You can also set an environment variable after Vercel generates a URL for your application and use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

...

```
const router = useRouter();
```

...

```
const origin =
    typeof window !== "undefined" && window.location.origin
      ? window.location.origin
      : "";

url = origin + router.asPath;
```

or

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

...

```
const {asPath} = useRouter();
```

...

```
const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN + asPath;
```

...
.env

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN='https://webaddress.com'
```